# SMS app crashing when tried to run on emulator and device

Tags: java, android

My MainActivity.java codes are given bellow:

```
package com.hoque.smser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mo, msg;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SendMSG();
    }

    private void SendMSG() {


        button.setOnClickListener(
                                  new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText phoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
                EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);


                final String no = phoneNo.getText().toString();
                final String msg = message.getText().toString();

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(no, null, msg, null, null);

            }
        }
        );

    }
}
```

My app is crashing whenever i am trying to launch it,it's just a SMS sender app.
I have added the following permissions on my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

I am a new programmer and currently learning java.
Thank you for providing me with your valuable time.

Comment: Add the logcat please

Answer (score 0):

> My app is crashing whenever i am trying to launch it

Thats because you haven't initialised your `button` variable before setting the click listener on it. You can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mo, msg;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_to_your_button); // change here

        SendMSG();
    }

    ...
}
```

Try to follow better coding practices like making your instance variables `private`, giving reasonable names to your methods (`setupSendButton()` instead of `SendMSG`), etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have modified the java file and now my app starts. However, when i try to click the button it crashes. I can not find any reason for it crashing.

Comment: @OnyHoque What is the error you are getting the logcat? What is your compile SDK version?

Comment: Thank you for the help and the tips. I am a new programmer and still learning. I rewrote the java file and now it runs fine. And Shaishav , i forgot to copy the logcats . No i modified the java file and the app runs fine. So i can not provide the logcats. Thank you everyone for your support and help. I really appreciate it .